# How can I show these labels when the user types in an incorrect format in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
    <template>
  <form class="form">
    <h1 class="form__title">Personal Info</h1>
    <p class="form__subtitle">
      Please provide your name, email address, and phone number
    </p>
    <div class="form__content">
      <div class="form__input" v-for="info in formInfo" :key="info.label">
        <div class="form__input__labels">
          <label :for="info.name" class="form__input__labels__name">{{
            info.label
          }}</label>
          <!-- <label
            class="form__input__labels__req"
            v-if="info.required && !info.inputValue"
            >this field is required</label> -->
          <label
            class="form__input__labels__req"
            :for="info.name"
            v-if="!info.isInputValid"
            >invalid {{ info.name }}</label
          >
        </div>
        <input
          :type="info.type"
          :name="info.name"
          class="form__input__item"
          :placeholder="info.placeholder"
          v-model="info.inputValue"
          @change="validateUserInpt(info.inputValue, info.type)"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="form__btn">Next Step</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const userInput = ref<string>("");
const userEmail = ref<string>("");
const userPhoneInput = ref<number | null>(null);

interface FormInfo {
  label: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  inputValue: string | number | null;
  required: boolean;
  isInputValid: boolean;
}

const formInfo = ref<FormInfo[]>([
  {
    label: "Name",
    type: "text",
    name: "name",
    placeholder: "e.g. Stephen King",
    inputValue: userInput.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
  {
    label: "Email Address",
    type: "email",
    name: "email",
    placeholder: "e.g. stephenking@lorem.com",
    inputValue: userEmail.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
  {
    label: "Phone Number",
    type: "number",
    name: "phone",
    placeholder: "e.g, +1 234 567 890",
    inputValue: userPhoneInput.value,
    required: true,
    isInputValid: false,
  },
]);

const validateUserInpt = (value: any, type: string) => {
  const nameRegex: RegExp = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; // regex for letters and spaces only
  const emailRegex: RegExp = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/; // regex for valid email format
  const phoneRegex: RegExp = /^\+?\d{1,3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}$/; // regex for valid phone format
  formInfo.value.forEach((info) => {
    switch (type) {
      case "name":
        info.isInputValid = nameRegex.test(value);
        break;
      case "email":
        info.isInputValid = emailRegex.test(value);
        break;
      case "phone":
        info.isInputValid = phoneRegex.test(value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
};
</script>
```

I want the "invalid name" , "invalid email", and "invalid phone" labels to show up when the user types sth in an incorrect format but nothing shows up and looks like it is not reactive, when i change the initial value of isInputValid to false, the label shows up but it doesn't go away when the user types.